# RxJS Subscribe with two arguments

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two observables which I want to combine and in subscribe use either both arguments or only one. I tried .ForkJoin, .merge, .concat but could not achieve the behaviour I'm looking for.

Example:

```
obs1: Observable<int>;
obs2: Observable<Boolean>;

save(): Observable<any> {
   return obs1.concat(obs2);
}
```

Then when using this function:

```
service.save().subscribe((first, second) => {
    console.log(first); // int e.g. 1000
    console.log(second); // Boolean, e.g. true
});
```

or

```
service.save().subscribe((first) => {
    console.log(first); // int e.g. 1000
});
```

Is there a possibility to get exactly that behaviour?

Hope someone can help!

**EDIT:**

In my specific use case `obs1<int>` and `obs2<bool>` are two different post requests: `obs1<int>` is the actual save function and `obs2<bool>` checks if an other service is running.

The value of `obs1<int>` is needed to reload the page once the request is completed and the value of `obs2<bool>` is needed to display a message if the service is running - independant of `obs1<int>`.

So if `obs2<bool>` emits before `obs1<int>`, that's not a problem, the message gets display before reload. But if `obs1<int>` emits before `obs2<bool>`, the page gets reloaded and the message may not be displayed anymore.

I'm telling this because with the given answers there are different behaviours whether the values get emitted before or after onComplete of the other observable and this can impact the use case.

Comment: what version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: rxjs version 6.1.0

Comment: Maybe useful - see this RxJs v6 solution using zip & param destructuring on the subscribe function - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993246/1882064

Answer (score 3):

There are several operators that accomplish this:

#### CombineLatest

This operator will combine the latest values emitted by both observables, as shown in the marble diagram:

[image: CombineLatest marble diagram]

```
obs1: Observable<int>;
obs2: Observable<Boolean>;

save(): Observable<any> {
   return combineLatest(obs1, obs2);
}

save().subscribe((val1, val2) => { 
   // logic
});
```

#### Zip

The `Zip` operator will wait for both observables to emit values before emitting one.

[image: Zip marble diagram]

```
obs1: Observable<int>;
obs2: Observable<Boolean>;

save(): Observable<any> {
   return zip(obs1, obs2);
}

save().subscribe((vals) => { 
   // Note Vals = [val1, val2]
   // Logic
});
```

Or if you want to use destructuring with the array

```
save().subscribe(([val1, val2]) => {
   // Logic
});
```

#### WithLatestFrom

The `WithLatestFrom` emits the combination of the last values emitted by the observables, note this operator skips any values that do not have a corresponding value from the other observable.

[image: WithLatestFrom marble diagram]

```
save: obs1.pipe(withLatestFrom(secondSource))

save().subscribe(([val1, val2]) => {
    // Logic
});
```

Comment: you excluded the most appropriate... forkJoin... withLatestFrom is not a viable option if the emission order is ambiguous because if the second source emits after the first, it's value may never be seen

Comment: @bryan60 I didn't include `forkJoin` because it waits until all observables emit an `onComplete` and then emits the last value. However `withLatestFrom` does emit current values, while it might not be as close to the answer as the others never hurts to have alternatives.

Comment: the question shows a "save" method, save methods 9/10 times are one time emission events, so it's better to use a one time emission operator for safety and explicitness.  Which also makes withLatestFrom a completely non viable option.

Comment: he tried and didn't use it correctly, the issue wasn't his choice of operator, it was how he tried to access the values... did you read the question entirely? the bug is in his subcribe method, he tries to access multiple arguments in an invalid manner.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I updated the question for more clarification. For the current use case forkJoin is more suitable because one obs is dependant on the other while the other is not vise versa. So waiting for both solves the timing issue. But, if there is a possibility to tell that obs2 can emit anytime without waiting for obs1, this would be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) for this purpose. Call them parallely and then if either of them is present then do something.

```
let numberSource = Rx.Observable.of(100);
let booleanSource = Rx.Observable.of(true);

Rx.Observable.forkJoin(
  numberSource,
  booleanSource
).subscribe( ([numberResp, booleanResp]) => {
  if (numberResp) {
    console.log(numberResp);
    // do something
  } else if (booleanResp) {
    console.log(booleanResp);
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: `forkJoin` will wait until all observables emit an `onComplete` and will only emit the last values of each.

Comment: Yes. I assume here we get both the results and we use either of them depending on our usage.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `zip` static method instead of `concat` operator.

```
save(): Observable<any> {
   return zip(obs1, obs2);
}
```

Then you should be able to do like the following:

```
service.save().subscribe((x) => {
    console.log(x[0]); // int e.g. 1000
    console.log(x[1]); // Boolean, e.g. true
});
```

Comment: With array index I can't see the variables.

Comment: Because 'zip' returns an observable array. I used the array index syntax to extract the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The exact operator to use depends on the specific details of what you are trying to solve.

A valid option is to use `combineLatest` - [Docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html):

```
obs1$: Observable<int>;
obs2$: Observable<Boolean>;
combined$ = combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$);

combined$.subscribe(([obs1, obs2]) => {
  console.log(obs1);
  console.log(obs2);
})
```

Comment: I like the way that both arguments are visible and I can decide to either use one or both.

Comment: @knnhcn yes, combineLatest is usually a safe choice when it comes to combining multiple streams

Answer (score 1):

Concat emits two events through the stream, one after the other has completed, this is not what you're after.

Merge will emit both events in the same manner, but in the order that they actually end up completing, also not what you're after.

What you want is the value of both items in the same stream event. forkJoin and zip and combineLatest will do this, where you're getting tripped up is that they all emit an array of the values that you're not accessing properly in subscribe.

zip emits every time all items zipped together emit, in sequence, so if observable 1 emits 1,2,3, and observable two emits 4,5; the emissions from zip will be [1,4], [2,5].

combineLatest will emit everytime either emits so you'll get soemthing like [1,4],[2,4],[2,5],[3,5] (depending on the exact emission order).

finally forkJoin only emits one time, once every item inside it has actually completed,a and then completes itself.  This is likely what you want more than anything since you seem to be "saving".  if either of those example streams don't complete, forkJoin will never emit, but if they both complete after their final value, forkjoin will only give one emission: [2,5]. I prefer this as it is the "safest" operation in that it guarantees all streams are completing properly and not creating memory leaks. And usually when "saving", you only expect one emission, so it is more explicit as well. When ever you see forkJoin, you know you're dealing with a single emission stream.

I would do it like this, personally:

```
obs1: Observable<int>;
obs2: Observable<Boolean>;

save(): Observable<any> {
   return forkJoin(obs1, obs2);
}

service.save().subscribe(([first, second]) => {
    console.log(first); // int e.g. 1000
    console.log(second); // Boolean, e.g. true
});
```

Typescript provides syntax like this to access the items in an array of a known length, but there is no way to truly create multiple arguments in a subscribe success function, as it's interface only accepts a single argument.