# How do I observe two rx sequences and subscribe with two closure arguments?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I want to observe two `behaviorRelays` with a single `observer`, wait for both `relays` to emitt their values, then in the `subscription` have two seperate `closure arguemts`, one for each `relay`. Something like this:

```
let one = firmwareService.basicIODeviceUnit.compactMap { $0?.canBeUpdated }
let two = firmwareService.motorDeviceUnit.compactMap { $0?.canBeUpdated }
        
Observable.of(one, two).flatMap{ $0 }.subscribe(onNext: { a, b in
    print("--", a, b)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The above code isn't allowed. The operators like `merge` or `zip` seem to bundle both relays into a single closure argumet so I guess they won't work. What do I use?

I have looked through this thread, so it should be possible, but I can't wrap my head around it since I use `swift`
[RxJS Subscribe with two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470406/rxjs-subscribe-with-two-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean because `zip` does exactly what you want. So does `combineLatest`.

```
let one = firmwareService.basicIODeviceUnit.compactMap { $0?.canBeUpdated }
let two = firmwareService.motorDeviceUnit.compactMap { $0?.canBeUpdated }

Observable.zip(one, two)
    .subscribe(onNext: { a, b in
        print("--", a, b)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! I think I got the syntax wrong. I wrote something like `Observable.of(one,two).zip().subscribe(onNext: { a, b` and that gave an error. Many thanks for clearing that up! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use combineLatest:

combineLatest is an operator which you want to use when value depends on the mix of some others Observables.
When an item is emitted by either of two Observables, combine the latest item emitted by each Observable via a specified closure and emit items based on the results of this closure.

For reference follow this -
[combineLatest meduim link](https://medium.com/swift-india/rxswift-combining-operators-combinelatest-zip-and-withlatestfrom-521d2eca5460)