# RxJs equivalent of Promise.all()

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the RxJs equivalent of Promise.all() whereby the then block only executes when all promises are resolved?

```
const request1 = this.http.get('/api/hello').toPromise() // returns a promise
const request2 = this.http.get('/api/there').toPromise() // returns a promise

Promise.all([request1, request2]).then(([response1, response2]) => {
  // executes if/when ALL the promises resolve
  console.log('response1', response1);
  console.log('response2', response2);
}).catch(err => {
  // executes if ANY ONE of the promises fail / reject
  console.log('err', err);
})
```

So what is the equivalent approach in RxJs? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise.all behavior with RxJS Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608025/promise-all-behavior-with-rxjs-observables)

Comment: [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**You can use [forkJoin](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin)**

> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and
>   only care about the final emitted value of each. You can use this
>   operator to issue multiple requests.
>
> **import { forkJoin, Observable } from "rxjs"**;

**Usage**

```
const request1 = this.http.get('/api/hello'); //return an observable
const request2 = this.http.get('/api/there') //return an observable

forkJoin([request1,request2]).subscribe((response)=>{

    //after all the successful requests 
    //response.forEach((eachRes)=>{console.log(eachRes)});
    //or response[0] , response[1]


});
```

Comment: or simply .subscribe(([res1,res2]) => {...}