# How to consolidate an Observable with informations by a second calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

For educative purpose, I'm trying to call a service that retrieve a list of Posts, and for each post, I would like to make a another call to this service to get the list of comments.

I'm using the data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

First here are the models I extracted for this service:

```
export interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  comments: PostComment[];
}

export interface PostComment {
  postId: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  body: string;
}
```

And here is my current status. My goal is to have an `Observable<Post>` with the property `comments` properly filled.

```
export class PostCommentsCombination implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  posts$?: Observable<Post[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.posts$ =this.http.get<Post[]> ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/').pipe(
      switchMap((posts) =>
        posts.map((post) =>
          this.http.get<PostComment[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${post.id}/comments`).pipe(
            map((comments) => {
              post.comments = comments;
              return post;
            })
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

But it says it cannot convert `Observable<Observable<Post>>` into `Observable<Post[]>`. I cannot blame him, but I'm not sure how to solve this?

Comment: You should be able to convert the `Observable<Observable<X>>` into an `Observable<X>` by calling something like `flatMap`.

Comment: @ziggystar that would be one part of it, but also, I need this `Observable<Observable<T>>` to be transformed in `Observable<T[ ]>`. Not sure why I don't have an array anymore

Comment: Maybe this? https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could `forkJoin` the requests to the comments, update the `post.comments` field and return the `post` back:

```
this.posts$ = this.http
  .get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(posts =>
      forkJoin(
        posts.map(post =>
          this.http
            .get<PostComment[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${post.id}/comments`)
            .pipe(map(comments => {
              post.comments = comments;
              return post;
            }))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzwheb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about forkJoin and I didn't see it on https://rxmarbles.com/

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```ts
ngOnInit(): void {

  const postsUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';

  this.posts$ = this.http.get<Post[]>(postsUrl).pipe(
    map(posts => posts.map(post =>
      this.http.get<PostComment[]>(`${postsUrl}${post.id}/comments`).pipe(
        map(comments => ({...post, comments}))
      )
    )),
    switchMap(postObservables => forkJoin(postObservables))
  );
  
}
```

Comment: Nice, a great alternative to @Joulukuusi thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
posts.map((post) => ...
```

is basically getting every post and mapping it to an Observable. So you end up with an array of Observables. What you want to do is resolve every Observable in the array to get the output you desire. If you are familiar with promises you want the rxjs equivalent of Promise.all, which is essentially forkJoin - see this post [Promise.all behavior with RxJS Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608025/promise-all-behavior-with-rxjs-observables)