# How to wait for multiple fetch calls to complete before calling the function

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api, rally

I am using Rally SDK to build a custom HTML chart. I am trying to retrieve user details from the rally. I am filtering the participants who have team features defined then sending the array to function to build a chart. But I am facing an issue as the array is not filtering data because of multiple fetch calls. How to resolve this issue.

```
_loadParticipants: async function () {
                const deferred= Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
                let teamFeatureStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                    model: 'portfolioitem/teamfeature',
                    fetch: ['c_CAPPMFeatureEstimatedHours', 'c_HSPDPrimaryCustomer', 'c_ProductRoadmapBU', 'c_ProductRoadmapQuarter', 'c_ProductRoadmapQuarterStatus',
                        'c_SHSComponent', 'Description', 'FormattedID', 'InProgressDate', 'Milestones', 'Name', 'Parent', 'PlannedEndDate', 'PlannedStartDate',
                        'Project', 'State', 'Blocked', 'BlockedReason', 'c_EstimateinTeamSprints',"_ref"
                    ],
                    limit: 300,
                    context: {
                        project: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.x/project/619025602727',
                        projectScopeUp: false,
                        projectScopeDown: false
                    }
                });
                teamFeatureStore.load({
                    callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                        if (success) {
                            const rootUrl = "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/";
                            records.map(async value => {
                                //call teamFeatures ref URL
                                const data = value.data
                                const teamFeaturesDetails = await fetch(rootUrl+data['_ref']);
                                const responseJsonObj = await teamFeaturesDetails.json();
                                const teamFeatureObj = responseJsonObj.TeamFeature
                                const directChildrenCount = teamFeatureObj.DirectChildrenCount
                                //check if participants created any userStories under TF
                                if(directChildrenCount>0){

                                    fetch(teamFeatureObj['CreatedBy']['_ref'])
                                        .then(response => response.json())
                                        .then( data => {
                                                const userObj = data.User
                                                const userEmail = userObj.EmailAddress;

                                                if (userEmail !== null) {
                                                    this.participants = this.participants.filter(email => email !== userEmail)
                                                    console.log("inside",this.participants.length)
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ).catch(error => {
                                        console.error('Error:', error);
                                    });
                                }

                            })
                            deferred.resolve(records)

                        }

                        else{
                            deferred.reject("Error _loadParticipants");
                        }

                    },

                    scope:this
                });
                this.participantsGlobalMap = this.participants.map(email=>{
                    return {
                        'userEmailIndex':email
                    }
                })
                this._buildDisplayTable()
                console.log("promise inside",deferred.promise)
                return deferred.promise
            }
```

and the function to display table

```
_buildDisplayTable: function () {
                var me = this
                console.log(this.participantsGlobalMap)
                Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
                    storeId:'skillStore',
                    fields:['userEmailIndex'],
                    data: {'items': this.participantsGlobalMap},
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'memory',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'items'
                        }
                    }
                });
                //
                console.log( Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('skillStore'))
                var resultsGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                    title:'Participants Details',
                    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('skillStore'),
                    columns: [
                        {text: 'User_Email', dataIndex: 'userEmailIndex',flex:1},
                    ],
                    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
                });
                this.GLOBAL_resultsPanel.add(resultsGrid);

                // Add ability to export CSV Summary
                this.GLOBAL_resultsPanel.add({
                    xtype: 'rallybutton',
                    text: 'Export CSV Summary',
                    handler: function () {
                        me._onCSVClickExportSummary();
                    }
                });

            },
```

Comment: Try forkJoin Related link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055280/rxjs-concat-three-promises-distinguish-results/34055587#34055587

Comment: I basically want both fetch to be completed before calling _buildDisplayTable and not to use any third-party library as I am using rally SDK. So how can I wait for both fetch to complete?